# Recursive approach for computing $(a,b) \mapsto a^b$

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms

As a programming exercise I was asked to implement a recursive approach for computing $a^b$ given two real $a,b \in \mathbb R, a>0$.

I assume this task has a typo, as a recursive approach makes sense when $b \in \mathbb Z$. But I am still wondering, is there some kind of recursive (not too terribly inefficient) method for approximating $a^b$ if $b$ is not an integer?

Comment: Returning the final recursive function by $if(b<=1) return$ $ pow(a,b);$ will help i guess.

Comment: The task would be implementing `pow()` *without* using that exact function.

Answer (score 0):

I here assume  that $b>0$.

$
 f(a,b) =
\begin{cases}
a*f(a,b-1),  & \text{if $b$ > 1} \\
a^b, & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$

Comment: So how do you compute $a^b$? That would be exactly the point of my question.

Comment: @flawr OK, for small b<1, there is no way to avoid using power function. I wanted to show the recursive part only

Comment: Why do you think there is no way to avoid a power function?

Comment: @flawr Because computers have limited operations and they use multiplication and additions for every mathematical calculation. Like many other functions, power functions are handled via Taylor Series expansion, or other numerical approximations.

Comment: I know, so what prevents you from recursively evaluating power series?

Comment: @flawr Yes you can do that, it is possible. But the question is until which order do you plan to keep adding terms?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have $$a^{(b/c)}$$Then you need to use two recursive functions or may be combine them in one.Your steps will be as following

1. A recursive function to compute the numerator power  $a^b$ which is easy
2. Then a recursive function to find the $c^{th}$ root of the answer you got after step 1.

The problem you have is making up the second function for which I will suggest using [Herons method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method) for finding square  roots. Herons method is itself recursive in nature.

For finding a $c^{th}$ root when $c$ is a power of $2$  e.g. $8$ in $\sqrt[8]{390625}$ keep on taking square root recursively and divide $c$ by $2$ every time you take a square root.The base case is when the root becomes $1$ e.g.
$$\sqrt[8]{390625}=\sqrt[4]625 = \sqrt[2]25 = 5 $$

So $5$ will be the answer

Doing this for odd roots seems a problem.Converting the fractional power ${b/c}$ into another form ${x/y}$ where $y=2^n$ will result in a good approximation.

You can do it by writing down $(b/c)$ in decimal form.Now convert this decimal form into fractional form such as $n/10^x$.Then divide both $n$(numerator) and $10^x$(denominator)  by $5*10^{x-1}$ to get $n/(5*10^{x-1})$ and $2$  respectively.So your fraction becomes

$$n/10^x = (n/5*10^{x-1})/(10^x/5*10^{x-1})=(n/5*10^{x-1})/2$$

Do the above fractional conversion before beginning the steps I listed.Then you will need to take the square root using Herons method only once after step 1